# Can someone tell me what frames (Brand & Model) accept 26 and 27.5 wheels??

Tags: mountain-bike

I have my Slayer 70 completely build up and i want to change the frame for a new one, but while i get the money for all the parts, i would like to fit the new frame on my 26 wheels and fork.

Comment: Frankly, it makes no sense to buy a new frame and base the choice on wheels and a fork you wish to reuse.  Just buy a new bike.

Comment: actually i found 2 frames that can use 26 or 27.5 wheels, the Banshee Rune and the Kona Process, i think is completely fine my thought about buying a frame based on wheels and fork, cause i dont have the money to buy an entire bike in one pay. So i can buy a frame and start using it with my parts while i get the rest of the money to buy 27.5 wheels and fork.

Comment: The point is that buying the parts for a bike is easily twice as expensive as buying the whole bike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, frames+forks are designed to take one wheel size (26", 27.5", 29", etc.; some are designed to take a different wheel size in the front and back but the specific wheel size is part of the frame+fork design).

However, if you can get the wheel into the frame+fork and align the brakes (in cases where possible, it is normally easier (in fact, often trivial) with disc brakes and more difficult with rim brakes), you could swap wheel sizes. This may be done to lower the bike (700c->650b for smaller riders) or to change handling characteristics or have more accessible parts (27"->700c) or just for fun.